# Has anyone successfully used Talend MDM community edition over SSL?

Tags: talend

We've managed to get talend MDM UI working fine over SSL, but we've not managed to get the MDM studio talk to the MDM server over SSL. Has anyone managed this?  I've not tried the data integration input steps yet over SSL either.

I tried the forums - no joy.

I suspect for some reason it's not possible - And the reason I suspect this is that when you add an MDM server in TOS it prompts for port, hostname, user and password. Nowhere does it prompt for protocol.

One assumes that the EE version must surely support this?  But we have a very simple model and wont be using EE as it would be OTT.

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this is a bug/unimplemented feature, and has been pencilled in to be fixed in 5.3.0 with luck!

https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TMDM-4912